# SQL script execution based on the language selected during installation Installshield

Tags: sql-server, installation, installshield-le

I am using installshield 2016 ultimate version and little new to this. We have bunch of sql script which needs to be run all the time during installation, creating a database is one of the sql script in it. We want to change the collation for the database based on the language selected during installation. I have used the custom action but it failed as the update statement has to be executed before the database connection is established or services are started. I have also tried to use SELECTED_LANGUAGE=0x0409 (for english) as script condition but it shows an error stating "An invalid conditional statement was supplied.

Need help to write correct condition and if not how can i execute the sql based on language selected.

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkh5F.png)

Comment: What databse is this for? mysql or sql-server? You listed both.

Comment: Sorry my bad it is for sql server Microsoft sql

Comment: I don't know how Installshield works, but provided you have a database creation script, you should be able to set the default collation when you do so. BOL here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql